# How to reintegrate a SVN branch into trunk with Netbeans?

Tags: svn, merge, netbeans-7.1, svn-reintegrate, svn-merge-reintegrate

I created a branch from trunk.
As development on my branch is finished, I want to merge (reintegrate) my branch into trunk.
Is there an option or setting to enable?
It seems Netbeans 7.1 isn't able to reintegrate a branch into trunk.

Am I wrong?

Comment: +1, I would very much like to know this, too.

Comment: +1 Me too, it just seems not to be possible without CLI

Comment: Did you create the branch with Netbeans? You could just use the command line svn merge --non-interactive {branch url}. The --non-interactive is to avoid asking what to do with conflicts, then you just resolve them and commit. TortoiseSVN if you are on Windows does provide a GUI for merges too if you don't want to use the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Netbeans 8.2 you can use "Merge Changes..." to do that (not sure if this is also in netbeans 7.x available):

1. Right click your project/folder/file you want to merge
2. Choose "Subversion" - "Copy" - "Merge Changes..."
3. Following the merging assistent

More information are here: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#merging

Answer (score -1):

just use another SVN user interface, for example TortoiseSVN or the svn command line tool, as those can do merges and will work on the same data as Netbeans SVN.

If you have some time to spare, you could read the section "SVN merges are broken" of http://ventspace.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/understanding-subversions-problems/ and learn about distributed version control systems like git or mercurial that were created (amongst other reasons) to provide working merging in version control.